# does squeezed coherent state form an overcomplete basis

Tags: coherent-states

Coherent states form an over complete bases, but how about squeezed coherent state? Do they form an over complete basis as well?

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  The simplest way to realize this is that the coherent states are related to the squeezed states by a unitary (squeezing) transformations - as given in [this wiki entry](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeezed_coherent_state#Operator_representation).  The measure induced by this transformation will pick up another piece because of the squeezing part of the transformation, which contains additional parameters: broadly speaking whereas coherent states obtained using elements of the Heisenberg-Weyl group, the squeezing transformation is of the SU(1,1) type, so the completeness relation is of course different.

If you have the stomach for it there is [older paper](http://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/0253-6102/32/3/471/meta) (behind a paywall I’m sorry to say) which gives details.

Comment: Thanks, how about for two modes? Lets say we apply two mode squeezing operation of the tensor product of two cohrent states? Does the resultant state form a basis for two mode states? and if yes whats the completness relation?